# Merge [mic] into [microphone]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[mic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mic) obviously refers to [microphone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microphone). Can we merge [mic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mic) into [microphone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microphone) and synonymize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and done.

```
updating post history, 29 rows affected
updating posts, 24 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 20 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [microphone] and [mic] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym mic -> microphone was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```